# How to uninstall PowerShell 5.1 on Windows after installing 72

Tags: windows, powershell

I just updated PowerShell to 7.2.1:

[image: Powershell 7.2.1]

But the old is still installed:

[image: Powershell 5.1]

How do I remove the old one? Having both installed is kinda redundant I suppose.

Comment: For compatibility reasons is why it's not overtaken when installing the new cross platform PowerShell. Type in pwsh to load the new shell.

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS THING!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You don't. **PowerShell Core** (6+) installs alongside **Windows PowerShell** (up to 5.1). **Windows PowerShell** still contains proprietary code that has not yet been open sourced, or never will be in the foreseeable future. The main difference between the two is that **PowerShell Core** runs on **.NET Core**, and **Windows PowerShell** relies on **.NET Framework**. There is no more new development for **Windows PowerShell**, as new features find their way into **PowerShell Core** instead.

There are *unrecommended and unsupported* ways to purge the system of **Windows PowerShell** but you will very literally break parts of Windows in the process. As of
`Version 21H1 (OS Build 22000.466)` **Windows PowerShell** remains a dependency of the core operating system and likely will be for some time yet.

Comment: So... when I hit WinKey + X that context menu still brings up the old powershell when clicking the powershell option can I change that to PS 7?

Comment: I'm actually not sure how or if that menu can be modified. You may want to search/ask on [su] since that would be more of an OS configuration.

Comment: Can the 7 version only be invoked directly from Start Menu then?

Comment: PowerShell 6+ is invoked by running `pwsh.exe` on Windows machines. If installed it should already be on the PATH. `powershell.exe` continues to invoke 5.1. On Linux, unless something changed recently, both `powershell` and `pwsh` will open PowerShell 6+.

Answer (score 0):

They run alongside so I think you must not do it.

Windows PowerShell ships with the OS and will always be the default until MS changes that. That is not happening anytime soon as MS has publically stated that though PSv5 is not getting any more focus or work, it is not going anywhere. Just like cmd.exe is not going anywhere

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).